# Sound not playing in my application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, windows

I am running 1 background process in my application...it continuously checks for some input...When proper input is entered of found..It will play Some wav file..

I have added 1 wav filled named as "ding.wav" into Resources..

and i have written following code in my application...
I am using System.Media namespace. and using .Net 4.0

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.Stream = Properties.Resources.ding;
player.Play();
```

but sound is not playing...

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong..!!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.ding);
player.Play();
```

You can also try this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Resources;
using System.IO;
namespace Win32
{
  public class Winmm
  {
    public const UInt32 SND_ASYNC = 1;
    public const UInt32 SND_MEMORY = 4;

    [DllImport("Winmm.dll")]
    public static extern bool PlaySound(byte[] data, IntPtr hMod, UInt32 dwFlags);
    public Winmm() { }
    public static void PlayWavResource(string wav)
    {
      // get the namespace 
      string strNameSpace= 
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToString();

      // get the resource into a stream
      Stream str = 
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(      strNameSpace +"."+ wav );
      if ( str == null ) return;
     // bring stream into a byte array
     byte[] bStr = new Byte[str.Length];
     str.Read(bStr, 0, (int)str.Length);
     // play the resource
     PlaySound(bStr, IntPtr.Zero, SND_ASYNC | SND_MEMORY);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to ensure that the file is loaded before you play it.

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.ding);
player.Load();
player.Play();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me (VS 2022, .net 6, C # 10) it worked:

1. Import the "ding.wav" file into the main directory.
2. Change in: Properties (ding.wav) - Copy to Output Directory to: Copy always.
   Later it was enough to:

   ```
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("ding.wav");
    player.Load ();
    player.Play ();
   ```